# JavaScript - Validating a Hex in Opera?

Tags: javascript, regex

This function works in Firefox, Chrome, IE9. Doesn't work in Opera.

```
function isValidHex(hex) { alert(hex);
    var strPattern = /^#([0-9a-f]{1,2}){3}$/i; alert(strPattern.test(hex));
    return strPattern.test(hex);
}
```

The hex going in is the same. The result of strPatter.test returns false in Opera and true in Firefox.

Tested.

```
#000000
#ffffff
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the regex is wrong already for that task as it would also match `#123a`. You want `^#([0-9a-f]{3}){1.2}$` probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex is incorrect. `#1234` would be correct too in this regex. User the regex `/^#([a-fA-F0-9]{3}|[a-fA-F0-9]{6})$/`.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue of what's going on in Opera, and as such, should probably be a comment (and there already is one)

Comment: @David Hedlund  Sorry, missunderstood the question

Comment: Wouldn't your regexp match also #QQQ ?

Answer (score 2):

If you swap the multipliers around, it works in Opera also:

```
function isValidHex(hex) {
  var objPattern = /^#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i;
  return objPattern.test(hex);
}
```

You would want to do that anyway, so that you match one or two groups of three digits (i.e. 3 or 3+3 characters), not three groups of one or two digits (i.e. 1+1+1, 2+1+1, 2+2+1 or 2+2+2 characters).

(Note that I also renamed the varaible from `strPattern` to `objPattern` as it contains a regular expression object, not a string. If you are using hungarian notation to specify the data type, the prefix has to match the actual data type, or it's only contraproductive.)

Comment: That makes me seriously wonder why one works in Opera and the other not.